# How to inject filter in app config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a filter I want to inject into module config to set value for some state title etc.

```
.config(["$stateProvider","$filter", function ($stateProvider,$filter) {
$stateProvider

.state('app.home', {
    url: '/',
    data: {
        title: $filter('myFilter')('trans.abc'),
    },
    views: {
        "content@app": {
            templateUrl: '---',
            controller: 'dummyController'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
    }
})`
```

Here is the filter

```
APP.filter('myFilter',getTranslate);

function getTranslate($rootScope){
   return function(text){
   return 'test title';
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see your filter, can you show us the full code ?

Comment: have a look please, I have added filter now

Comment: Is this your full code ?

Comment: you just added filter part which I advise below, not a filter code it self :) p.s. you forget to add $filter at start `["$stateProvider", "$filter", function `

Comment: Please have a look now,

Comment: i think you got another module for your filter. it is not full code as well. if that is the case then you will will have to inject filter in your main module.

Comment: exactly @AmeerHamza you are right, where I should Inject in main module  ?

Comment: @naCheex can you share full javascript code here ?